# Testflight unable to install an app

Tags: ios, download, testflight

I have several tester who have registered to testflight and connected their devices... they have different ios models... iOS 6 and above... but all of them share the same problem.

When they click the install button of an app from "safari" or the "testflight" app itself...

the app starts to download... reaches about 90% and an error message appears...."UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD APPLICATION. the "app" could not be installed at this time.

Now i have about 30 testers... 7 of them have the same issue... the others have succesfuly installed the app with no problem what so ever...

It seems completely random bug to me as there are no correlations between the phone models or ios versions... which are by the way all 6 and above....

So... what do i do. please help

Comment: Did you add your devices which you cannot install the app to your distribution profile ? This issue is related to code signing.

Comment: yeap. added the device to destribution profile.

Comment: did you then redownload the distribution profile to xcode and make sure you selected the correct profile when uploading to TestFlight? Also, are you using the TestFlight desktop app?

Answer (score 6):

there could be many reasons of it Below are some of those mentioned

1. You are using Developer profile instead of Adhoc Distribution profile
2. You are using app identifier that is different from the one that belongs to your profile
3. There could be issue with iCloud/Gamecenter enabled/disabled

In any case ask the testers to connect the device to PC/Mac open **iPhone Configuration Utility** and see the logs after you press install from the build in testflight.This will give them a deep insight of whats going wrong there.Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure if IPCU still allows you to look at the logs - if not, XCode allows you to look at the device console.

Answer (score 2):

For me Setting Build Active Architecture to NO... works and installed successfully

Comment: Can you give a more in depth description on how to do this please?

Comment: Ya what does this mean, please add screenshots

Answer (score 2):

For my case, uninstalling/reinstalling the TestFlight app from testers' phones seemed to help, as though the installs had got into an irretreivably bad state.

For anyone else going through this, worth noting that iTunes Connect support couldn't help, and Apple Developer Support wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, it seems testflight is down. It was not showing in the [system status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) from the beginning but they updated it to reflect the period I experienced the problem.

I had around 70 testers, only one was able to download, that tester just kept on retrying.

[image: testflight]

Comment: Another outage affecting TestFlight today, August 30, 2016. *sigh* If only I had thought to check this status page before I wasted hours trying to debug why my new builds wouldn't install! Thanks @Lyck for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the original problem was solved by using the proper provisioning profile.

But, for future googlers' record, I was getting the profile installation error (seen in the console log) *0xe800800b* which seemed to be an uncommon error code as I couldn't find anything.

Finally, found something mentioning a "bad UDID" would cause a range of possible error codes and I had 19 old ones in mine (damn *Select All*).

Selecting only the few I really cared (and knew) solved the issue (never bothered to try to find which was the bad one).

Answer (score 0):

i delete my adhoc provisioning profile after adhoc provisioning profile generated by xcode. it's working fine